# Retrieving an array's name by its ID

Tags: java, android, xml

May be a dumb question but I'm having a trouble figuring that out.

I have several string arrays in my arrays.xml, for example

```
<string-array name="words_array">
    <item>Yes</item>
    <item>No</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="numbers_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

And in my java code I obtain them using TypedArrays:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.words_array);
```

Is it possible to get arrays' names, for example, "words_array" from variable "ta" dynamically by their IDs?

Comment: The ID is words_array and the name is words_array, so if you have the ID you have the name. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Nickel Technically, the id is an `int` value stored in a variable called `words_array`. I think the OP is asking how to get this variable name during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.array.words_array);
```